# Xampp + Wordpress, Error 500 .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I'm trying to host a local WordPress site on my machine using Xampp.

I got everything working, I can get on the site etc. However I can't change the Permalinks without editing the .htaccess, and here lies my problem.

I've removed the "#" in front of the "Load rewrite" module in Xampp, and also changed the "AllowOverride All".

If I add in my own .htaccess file into the WordPress root (Xampp/htdocs/mysite/.htaccess) then the error comes up, otherwise it doesn't. I have hidden files visible yet I can't see a .htaccess file there, even adding a blank one breaks it.

Error from webpage:

`The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.`

Error form Apache Error Log:

`[Fri May 16 13:45:48.885862 2014] [core:alert] [pid 18435] [client ::1:54974] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PMD-new/.htaccess: Invalid command '{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\cocoartf1038\\cocoasubrtf360', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/PMD-new/wp-admin/options-permalink.php?settings-updated=true`

.htaccess File:

http://pastebin.com/vb3zScdx

When I remove the .htaccess file it works fine, but I can't change the permalinks.

I'm new when it comes to this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: look in the apache error logs.

Comment: Edited to show Apache Error log, makes no sense to me.

Comment: Add your .htaccess file.

Comment: Is your .htaccess a RTF file? It has to be plain text.

Comment: Added PasteBin of .htaccess file. @RolandJansen I believe so, the extension was removed.

Comment: Which editor do you use? TextEdit's default format is RTF! Check the editor settings.